# Nhibernate won't map models from another solution

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I made a "common" and put my models there so I could use them in my other projects, that way all of my projects know the model I use without knowing each other, but when I try to open a session factory and map those models using fluent nhibernate it would just skip my mapping. Is there any way I can map those models without adding a reference to fluent nhibernate to my common project?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell FH to look for types in specific assemblies. Wherever you perform FH configuration, needs a reference to your common project, but I don't see that as being problematic. This is an example of an auto persistence helper:

```
    public class AutoPersistenceModel
    {
        public AutoPersistenceModel GetModel()
        {
            var model = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Common.YourClassName>(new AutomappingConfiguration()) // add types-to-map 
                               .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<TableNameConvention>() // add generic conventions
                               .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModel>() // add specific conventions
                               .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModel>(); // add mapping overrides
            return model;
        }
    }

    public class AutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// defining which types should be auto-mapped...
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override bool ShouldMap(System.Type type)
        {
            var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
            return 
                interfaces.Any(
                    x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityWithTypedId<>));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// defining which properties should be auto-mapped...
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="member"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
        {
            return base.ShouldMap(member) && member.CanWrite &&
                   !member.MemberInfo.IsDefined(typeof (NotMappedAttribute), false);
        }
    }
```

...

```
sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
.Database(sqlConfig)
.Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(new AutoPersistenceModel().GetModel()))
.CurrentSessionContext<T>()
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, but I've find a much easier way to do what I wanted, 
I changed my the session factory mapping config from m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf()
To 
m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf() 
and it started working again